# How should I handle Chrome tabs that don't yet have a content script loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to extend some of the handling of messaging between my background process and content scripts. In the normal course of things my background process sends a message via postMessage() and the content script replies via another channel with a response. However I would like to now extend the background process to fall-back to something else if the content script can't find a valid thing on the page. It's when looking at this I discovered a problem when sending a message to blank or system pages. As the tabs don't have content scripts loaded there is nothing to receive the posted message. This generates warnings in the console logs but otherwise no ill effects. However:

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
//
// When clicked we send a message to the current active tab's
// content script. It will then use heuristics to decide which text
// area to spawn an edit request for.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    var find_msg = {
        msg: "find_edit"
};
    try {
        // sometimes there is no tab to talk to
    var tab_port = chrome.tabs.connect(tab.id);
    tab_port.postMessage(find_msg);
    updateUserFeedback("sent request to content script", "green");
    } catch (err) {
        if (settings.get("enable_foreground")) {
            handleForegroundMessage(msg);
        } else {
            updateUserFeedback("no text area listener on this page", "red");
        }
    }
});
```

Doesn't work. I would expect the connect or the postMessage to throw an error I can trap, however the console log is filled with error messages including:

```
Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

But I do not end up in the catch statement.

Comment: Read the value of [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-lastError) to find out whether an error has occurred.

Comment: @RobW: that doesn't seem to defined in this case. In fact something weird is going on because I'm seeing inconsistent catch events each time I trace through the code in the debugger. Is this some sort of async magic going on?

Comment: Insert a `debugger;` statement to find out.

Comment: @RobW:I'm tracing through with Chrome's debugger as it is which I think is changing it's behaviour w.r.t async events compared to when I run it normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I couldn't do it with connect, I had to use the one shot sendMessage() which has a call-back function when the response comes in. That can then be interrogated for success and the state of lastError. The code now looks like this:

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
//
// When clicked we send a message to the current active tab's
// content script. It will then use heuristics to decide which text
// area to spawn an edit request for.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var find_msg = {
        msg: "find_edit"
    };
    // sometimes there is no content script to talk to which we need to detect
    console.log("sending find_edit message");
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, find_msg, function(response) {
        console.log("sendMessage: "+response);
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError && settings.get("enable_foreground")) {
            handleForegroundMessage();
        } else {
            updateUserFeedback("sent request to content script", "green");
        }
    });
});
```